# Get parent of appended element

Tags: jquery

I have inserted elements into the DOM with `appendTo()`. I am tryng to traverse the DOM from inside the appended elements to get a reference back to the element that the appened elements were appended to. But this does not seem to be working for me. I've done some troubleshooting by outputing the result of `parent()` to the console. Each time I step back one level I get a result from `parent()` until I reach the parent of the appended element. At that point `parent()` returns an empty set.

Here's an example of the code to illustrate this problem:

```
  <div class="menu">
     <span class="like current"></span>
     <span class="done"></span>
     <span class="add"></span>
     <span class="report"></span>
     <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-content">
           <p>This function is not yet implemented</p>
           <p>
              <a class="cancel" onclick="cancel_panel(this)">Cancel</a>
           </p>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

`div.panel` has been appended to `div.menu` with `appendTo()` and `div.panel-content` has been appended to `div.panel` with `appendTo()`

What I'm trying to achieve is to remove class `current` from `span.like` on clicking the Cancel link.

I've tried:

```
 $(elem).closest("div.menu").children("span.current").removeClass("current");
```

(where elem is a reference to the `a` element of the Cancel link)

But it doesn't work. `$(elem).closest("div.menu")` returns an empty set instead of `div.menu`

In further troubleshooting, `$(elem).parent()` gives me the expected reference to the `p` tag, `$(elem).parent().parent().parent()` gives me the expected reference to `div.panel`. But `$(elem).parent().parent().parent().parent()` returns an empty set.

What's going on here? Do appended elements not respond in the same way as real elements when traversing the DOM? Does jquery loose the plot with nested appends? How can I get a reference to back to the `div.menu`?

Comment: Spans aren't typically self-closing. What's your doctype?

Comment: in the real code they are not - code here is just truncated/simplified for the purpose of the question

Comment: Seems to work here ...  http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/mEJbF/1/
all i changed was that i took out the `onclick` and made it into a `click` event of jQuery

Comment: @hungerpain: You're right it does work. After rexamining my code I found the problem - I had removed the panel from the DOM before removing the current class instead of after.

Answer (score 1):

I tried reproducing your problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fvYNF/) with the script:

```
$(function() {

    var elem = $('<a class="cancel">Cancel</a>')
        .click(cancel_panel)
        .appendTo($(".panel-content").children().last());


    function cancel_panel() {                 
        $(elem).closest("div.menu")
        .children("span.current")
        .removeClass("current");
    }     
});
```

& the HTML above. But couldn't find any problems with :

```
$(elem).closest("div.menu").children("span.current").removeClass("current");
```

Do have a look at it & check if the problem lies else where.

Answer (score 0):

Try find your "like current" class and rename to "like" at that element

Comment: sorry, this is not an answer to my question

Answer (score 0):

```
$(elem).parents().filter(".menu").children("span.current").removeClass("current");
```

I have done a test [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KbSjG/4/) and that seems to work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. jquery DOM traversal of appended elements works just fine. hungerpain's jsfiddle demo proved there is no issue with the part of the code that I included in my question. It was something else. After re-examining my code I found that I had removed `div.panel` from the DOM before I was attempting to traverse up above it, so no wonder it didn't work!